# GRPC Permission denied on Google Pub/Sub [ERROR 7]

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to publish message to a topic on Google Cloud pubsub. But I get a `Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED`, I'm running on localhost trying to publish to a regular Cloud PubSub.

I instantiate the client and get the topic I want to publish on:

```
import { Encodings, PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const client = new PubSub({
  credentials: JSON.parse(
    readFileSync(
      '/Users/me/pubsub/publisher/mb-sandbox.json'
    ).toString()
  )
});

const topic = client.topic('dummy_topic');
```

Where mb-sandbox.json is the credentials for the pubsub authorized service account. I also tried setting & using `$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var.

But this seems to work properly because I can retrieve the correct ID of my gcp project using: `client.auth.getProjectId()`

When I try to publisher a message (which should respect the schema):

```
const DUMMY_MSG = {
    type: 'CARD',
    severity: 'INFO',
    user_id: 2000,
    text_content: 'TEST MESSAGE'
 };

const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(DUMMY_MSG));

const messageId = await topic.publishMessage({ data: dataBuffer });
```

I get a `Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.` Which is the 403 equivalent on GRPC if I'm not mistaken.

```
{
  code: 7,
  details: 'User not authorized to perform this action.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

I followed GCP Nodejs code samples, my service account is definitely recognized & has the permissions to publish on Cloud PubSub.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I was stuck on this for a day but I found the way right after posting the question...

Someone already solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494904/18495180). I had to specifically add authorization to pubsub publisher service account on the topic I want to send messages to.

Setting up role from the service account pannel isn't working for some reason, do it from Topic authorization pannel.

Answer (score -1):

It's the error of the service account that you are using please be sure that whatever the service account you are using has got required role to related to pubsub eg->role (pub/sub publisher)

Comment: Thanks, I had to specifically add those authorizations from the topic itself using service account email adresse, adding pubsub publisher role from the service account pannel doesn't make it work.

Comment: This is a low effort answer. Can you provide more information, maybe a few steps on how to achieve what you mention in the answer?